# String.Contains Function in Visual Basic 2008 or 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

**How do I find a unique string that contains in a single .txt file with different strings in each line?**

---

Example:
The .txt file contains the following

012345
023456
034567
045678
056789

Then I want to find one of the set of numbers.

---

**This is what I want to happen~**

```
Dim stN As String = TextBox1.Text

If stN.contains(.txt file) Then
    'Anything to do here
Else
    MsgBox("Your input number is incorrect", "ERROR")
End If
```

Comment: I would understand if your pseudo code would be the other way around: `If .txt-file.Contains(stN) Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your pseudo code should be the other way around: `If .txt-file.Contains(stN) Then`.

So you want to know if a string equals one line of a text-file:

```
Dim lines = File.ReadLines(path)
Dim fileContainsLine = lines.Any(Function(l) l.Trim.Equals(TextBox1.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

If you don't want to compare case-insensitively use `l==TextBox1.Text` instead. If the `Trim` is also unnecessary you could simplify it to:

```
Dim fileContainsLine = lines.Contains(TextBox1.Text)
```

Comment: The other way around worked. Thank you for your fast response!

Comment: I have one more question. Please refer to this other link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678086

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little Linqpad program, but you would probably want to read in the file one time and cache it.

```
    Sub Main
      If (CheckContains("023456")) Then
        Console.WriteLine("True")
      Else 
        Console.WriteLine("False")
      End If
    End Sub

    Function CheckContains(inputVal as String) as Boolean
      Dim query = From line In File.ReadAllLines("C:\code\so\sample.txt") _
      Select line

      return query.Contains(inputVal)
    End Function
```

Comment: You could reduce your code to: `If File.ReadAllLines(path).Contains("023456") Then`