# How to remove a used string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Now, I want to remove the string in the .txt file that the user used. This is to make it invalid for use.

---

*Thanks to Tim Schmelter for the [corrected code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677889/string-contains-function-in-visual-basic-2008-or-2012/18677960#18677960).*

```
If .txt file.Contains(stN) Then
    'Do anything here
    'Then I want to remove the string used.
End If
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to rewrite the entire file:

```
Dim newLines = File.ReadAllLines(path).
    .Where(Function(l) Not l.Trim.Equals(stN, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) )
File.WriteAllLines(path, newLines)
```

If you don't want to use Trim and the case insensitive comparison:

```
.Where(Function(l) l <> stN)
```

**Edit**: Are you using .NET 3.5? Then `File.WriteAllLines` does not accept an `IEnumerable(Of String)` but only `String()`. You need to create one from the query:

```
File.WriteAllLInes(path, newLines.ToArray())
```

Comment: Your modified question is  not clear anymore. First you wanted to remove lines from a file which equal a given string. Now `num` is a single string and it's not clear if it contains lines or whatever.

Comment: @AldwinBabierra: So do you want to remove  complete lines if they match the input string? Or do you want to remove words from the file that equal that string?

Comment: to remove lines that match the input string

Comment: Then put the code where you have the string, the path and you want to remove them ;)

Comment: @AldwinBabierra: Are you using .NET 3.5? Then `File.WriteAllLines` does not accept an `IEnumerable(Of String)` but only `String()`. Then you need to create one from the query: `File.WriteAllLInes(path, newLines.ToArray())`. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much. So helpful :] Sorry man. can't rep you yet.

Answer (score 0):

A file isn't line based (or even character based), so you can't remove a line from it. The smallest change possible is to rewrite the part of the file from where that line started to the end of the file, which is not trivial. The easiest solution is usually to rewrite the entire file.

Read the file, and write it back without the matching line:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
lines = lines.Where(s => s != theString).ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines);
```